# Adding double click event listener in CKEditor5 React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

Im using React. Installed according to these instructions, used online builder:
[Integrating a build from the online builder](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html#integrating-a-build-from-the-online-builder)

I'm trying to add a double click event listener on editor using this instruction:  [How to listen on a double-click?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/how-tos.html#how-to-listen-on-a-double-click-for-example-link-elements).

When I try to import: `import { DomEventObserver } from 'ckeditor5/src/engine';`,
I get an error:`Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules`

What am i doing wrong?